# Is not being able to call a git function outside submodule root a git submodule feature or a bug?

Tags: git, git-submodules

`git submodule foreach 'if echo "$sm_path" | grep just_this_one ; then git rev-parse HEAD ||:; fi'`

- gives : just_this_one's sha1

`git submodule foreach 'if echo "$sm_path" | grep just_this_one ; then cd somewhere; git rev-parse HEAD ||:; fi'`

- gives : error not a repository '.git'

`git submodule foreach 'if echo "$sm_path" | grep just_this_one ; then cd somewhere; git -C .. rev-parse HEAD ||:; fi'`

- gives : just_this_one's sha1

Is this a bug or a feature?

What can I do to pass through it if I want to run this command:
`git submodule foreach 'make -C somewhere all'`
where the makefile contains some git function calls.
I would like to also still be able to call the makefile outside git submodule foreach.

---

```
$ git --version
git version 2.23.0
```

Comment: Yes, that is a bug or a feature. Git has set the environment variable `GIT_DIR` to a relative path. Changing directories within the submodule causes the environment variable to be invalid. If Git were to set it to an absolute path, you could move within the submodule and still have some commands work. Note that the *working tree* path may or may not be in an environment variable as well, and that may or may not *also* be a relative path, so it's best not to change out of the directory.

Comment: If it's really necessary to cd around, consider checking for any relative-path Git variables and setting them to absolute-paths instead. It's not really clear to me which ones to check, here, though GIT_DIR, GIT_WORK_TREE, and GIT_INDEX_FILE are probably the main three.

Comment: Your other option is to unset all the Git variables. That might be safer. I'm not sure if there's an Officially Approved way to do this, either...

Comment: @torek "*I'm not sure if there's an Officially Approved way to do this*" `unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)`

Comment: `git submodule foreach 'unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars); cd somwhere; git rev-parse HEAD || :'` works for me.

Comment: On my phone at the moment, what happens if you try ``GIT_DIR=`git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir` git submodule foreach`` etc?

Comment: @jthill this does not work. Not sure to use it correctly though.

Comment: @phd this does work. But it would be pretty nice if I could have a global command so I don't have to add for each 'git submodule foreach'  call